# Running Apache CXF on top of Atmosphere in Apache Karaf 3.0 (OSGI Environment)

Tags: java, osgi, cxf, servlet-3.0, apache-karaf

I'm trying to implement Server Push/Reverse Ajax/Comet Technologies like HTTP Streaming or SSE, etc.. using Apache CXF - JAX-RS RESTFul services (> CXF 2.7.x - Supports Servlet 3.0 & JAX-RS 2.0 Async Support). Right now I'm evaluating to use Atmosphere or Cometd or similar frameworks to run smoothly in my Karaf OSGI environment without much complications. 
Please let me know how to programatically configure Atmosphere to run on top of CXF in my OSGI world where there is no web.xml... It would be great if someone can guide me with a sample.. Thanks

[Not much help in this - But this is what I exactly want to answer for!!](http://atmosphere-framework.2306103.n4.nabble.com/Atmosphere-OSGi-and-CXF-how-it-works-td4653001.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ditched [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) (which does nothing but [servlet 3 async spec](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html) + broadcast features with high-level abstraction).

[FYR](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/servlet-3-0-asynchronous-api-or-atmosphere-easy-decision/): Still some may prefer atmosphere over Servlet 3 - due to its abstraciton. But for my case, it was too bloated!

Instead, I wrote a Simple [Async Servlet 3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-reverseajax1/) - that runs on a Servlet 3 container. (Which was more than sufficient for my requirement)

For Client-side support - I chose [portal.js](https://github.com/flowersinthesand/portal) - A clean cross-browser JS framework for Comet/Reverse Ajax techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have samples for you since I never used those frameworks before, but aren't those just servlets that you just configure as std. Servlets? If so you just need to use the default http-Service configuration. For samples on how to use that take a look at the pax-web [samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples).